# Extracting 100,000 rows without stalling in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

My database currently has over 200,000 records and I have this query which has 3 joins and I'm worried that with these joins selecting the rows might take too long and stall my query. Is there a recommended way to select so many records like some preloader while doing the `SELECT`? I'm open to anything.

My query

```
-- Select all records
SELECT cust.firstname, cust.lastname, cust.phone1, cust.phone2, cust.mobile1, cust.mobile2, cust.regas, cust.regpol,
    cust.province, cust.city, cust.brgy, cust.unit, cust.vill, cust.condo, cust.servtype,
    cust.primary, cust.override_pst, dist.name, order.created, order.branch_id 'selectedbranch', order.status,
    order.delivery_date, order.date_acknowledged, order.date_dispatched, order.date_delivered, order.date_cancelled
    FROM sl_customers cust
    LEFT JOIN sl_orders `order` ON order.customer_id = cust.id
    LEFT JOIN sl_branches branch ON order.branch_id = branch.id
    LEFT JOIN sl_distributors dist ON branch.distributor_id = dist.id
    ORDER BY order.id DESC
```

And, yes, all columns used for `JOIN` are indexed.

Comment: Please add the query, so we have an idea what you are referring to. Can you clarify also what run times you are experiencing for a query of this size from a dataset of the size you specify? It sounds like you might be worried about a future problem, rather than one you are actually having. Slow queries, btw, are not "stalled" - they just take a long time. There are several things you can do to improve query performance.

Comment: Is the query itself slow? Is the *fetching* of data slow? What exactly is slow? What exactly is the query? We need some more details here. No, there is no "SELECT preloader".

Comment: How long does this query take to run? And, what hardware are you running on? (i.e. is it capable for the load you are placing on it)?

Comment: I'd first assume all those `LEFT JOIN`s were causing the slowdown. Try making them all `INNER`, then `UNION` the result with all customers who have no orders.

Comment: If you are indeed returning 100,000 entries, then it's not an issue for MySQL to find them (which is what indexes are for), the issue is in reading them, sending down the pipe, receiving and then rendering it. Bottom line is that for so many records, you need to ask yourself what are you doing and why do you need 100k of them returned. Naturally, it will take time.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider doing the query as an **unbuffered query**. Large result sets can take up a lot of memory, and in php, most of the common database extensions default to buffering the results into memory for speed and ease of use, but at the cost of memory consumption and response latency. It's a great default for most result sets which are small.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

If current memory usage levels are acceptable though, I would stick with buffered queries. They're much nicer to deal with from a programmers perspective.